# Makefile provides blank tex files

Tags: makefile, latex

I am currently in the process of writing quite a large document, that I divided into multiple chapters. What I chose to do is to put each chapter in a different file, and then compile them with a makefile into one big document. When I type make get in the terminal, the .tex docs appear with the right name in my folder but completely blank.
Here is my makefile :

```
pdf:
    pdflatex --shell-escape file.tex
clean:
    rm -f chapter1.tex
    rm -f chapter2.tex

get:
    sed -e '/BEGIN_BOOK/,/END_BOOK/!d' ../01-chapter1/chapter1.tex> chapter1.tex
    sed -e '/BEGIN_BOOK/,/END_BOOK/!d' ../02-chapter2/chapter2.tex> chapter2.tex
    
diff:
    git latexdiff HEAD -- --main file.tex --latexopt "--shell-escape"
```

But if I replace these blank ones with the correct files, the make command works properly and I get what I want.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with makefiles or with latex.  It seems to be a problem with your usage of `sed`.  If you put those same `sed` commands at a shell prompt I'm sure you'll get the same results as you get from running `make get`.  Since you don't give us any information about the structure of your `.tex` files or why you want to run these `sed` commands, we can't really help.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I'm not really sure how these commands work, I used the same makefile as my uni teacher did for his but changed it, without really knowing what was going on. What can I say about the tex files that could help ?

Comment: Well, you could explain what these `sed` commands are trying to do.  What is the difference between the file `../01-chapter1/chapter1.tex` (the input) and the file you want as output `chapter1.tex`?  I'm afraid that if you don't even understand your environment sufficiently to explain what you want to do at a high level, there's little hope we can help you do it.

Comment: what I was trying to do is just import the .tex files from other folders. I am sorry I dont really know much (if not anything at all about this). I think im going to look into a simpler way of doing this. Thank you for your time

Comment: If you just want the same file, why use `sed` with all this fancy stuff?  Why not just copy the file: `cp ../01-chapter1/chapter1.tex .` ?

Comment: this is exactly what I wanted, thank you very much for your help. I wanted to use these sed commands because my uni teacher did, but it works fine for me without them. thanks again

Comment: Those `sed` commands will only work if you have special keywords like `BEGIN_BOOK` and `END_BOOK` in your `.tex` files.

Comment: I got the sed commands to work thank you. They are actually useful because in the chapters I wrote, I include packages, and \begin{document} etc, that is not needed in the main file, but still allows me to compile each chapter separately. Thank you very very much for the help.

Comment: Instead of using this complex setup you could simply have a header file (`hdr.tex`) containing only the preamble, a footer file (`foot.tex`) containing only the footer, put only the chapters' body in your `chapterN.tex` files and input them all in the top `file.tex`. To compile your chapters separately simply add `chapterN_alone.tex` files in which you input only `hdr.tex`, `chapterN.tex ` and `foot.tex`.